# Problem with Graphics/locking up

Tags: release-freya, graphic-drivers, power

Sometimes, when the computer screen goes off, my laptop will flash the screen on black for a second, give me a cursor for less time that, and then go off. It then repeats this indefinitely. When I was installing via the live CD, it did the same thing, but it did not while I was installing without the live CD. This may because I moved the mouse more, or it took less time. Anyways, I am pasting my specs below. I have had this problem with both the open source driver, and the latest driver from NVIDIA. I have similar issues when waking from sleep.

Lenovo ThinkPad W510

Intel® Core™ i7 CPU       Q 720  @ 1.60GHz

11.7 GiB (12 installed, for some reason the graphics is taking 256 MB)

NVIDIA Corporation GT216GLM [Quadro FX 880M] (rev a2)

240 GB SSD

Fresh install of Elementary OS 0.3 Freya (64-bit) with latest updates

Comment: This sounds like a GPU problem that cannot likely be replicated without the hardware.